# Access annotated method from parent class with reflections.org

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, annotations

I have this code

```
public static SelenideElement findElementByTitle(String elementName) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Set<Field> annotated = new Reflections(lastInitialized, new FieldAnnotationsScanner()).getFieldsAnnotatedWith(ElementTitle.class);

        for (Field field : annotated) {
            ElementTitle annotation = field.getAnnotation(ElementTitle.class);
            if (annotation.value().equals(elementName)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                SelenideElement el = (SelenideElement) field.get(page(lastInit));
                return el;
            }
        }
        throw new AutotestError("Element not found: " + elementName);
```

It worked just fine before I actually implemented inheritance and it appears that my code can't access annotated fields from parent class. If I set package access I get exceptions because of ambiguity (got several same annotations throughout different classes, for example the "Next" button).

Here's the code which sets lastInitialized and lastInit fields (PAGES_PACKAGE is just a string pointing to the package containing all of my page object classes)

```
public static void initPage(String pageName) throws Exception {
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = new Reflections(PAGES_PACKAGE).getTypesAnnotatedWith(PageTitle.class);

        for (Class classToInit : annotated) {
            PageTitle annotation = (PageTitle) classToInit.getAnnotation(PageTitle.class);
            if (annotation.value().equals(pageName)) {
                classToInit.newInstance();
                lastInitialized = substringAfter(classToInit.toString(), "class ");
                lastInit = classToInit;
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new AutotestError("Can't find page to init: " + pageName);
    }
```

What I want to do is I want to have a Main page which has all the general fields every other tab on the website does and to have all of my website's "tabs" inherit from it while being able to access parent fields as if they were my current page's.

Comment: what do you mean by `can't access annotated fields from parent class. `

Comment: exactly what I said - my method only sees fields from the class I initialized last, not from it's parent

Comment: because you limited scan to that single class `new Reflections(lastInitialized` it would be better to just scan that fields using normal reflections, this library is mostly used to scan not-loaded classes to prevent loading of not needed classes.

Comment: does that mean I cannot use this library to access the parent class of a loaded class? I'm kind of new to reflections and a colleague of mine recommended me this library

Comment: If this class does not match package filter (`lastInitialized` in your code) - then not. You could do multiple scans - but then it does not make any sense and it would be pretty slow. Imho in your case it would be best to just use normal reflections to fetch fields.

Comment: but what if the field names are ambiguous? For instance I have 2 fields with annotations "Enter button", although the xpaths are different and they are different buttons

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that and how using normal reflections vs this library changes anything here